# Trying to install Oracle Database 19c on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, ubuntu

I've been trying to install oracle 19c on my ubuntu 19.04 machine, but I'm receiving the following exceptions that I copied from the .log installation file.

```
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'libasmclntsh19.ohso libasmperl19.ohso client_sharedlib' of makefile '/home/yuri/Downloads/Oracle/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/tmp/InstallActions2019-10-06_12-55-49PM/installActions2019-10-06_12-55-49PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

Could someone help me solve this problem ?

Comment: What does the file `/tmp/InstallActions2019-10-06_12-55-49PM/installActions2019-10-06_12-55-49PM.log` contain? Also you might want to look at [this question at community.oracle.com](https://community.oracle.com/thread/455284?start=15&tstart=0) and/or [this blog entry at gemsofprogramming.wordpress](https://gemsofprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/installing-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-a-hard-journey-but-its-worth-it/).

Comment: The file is quite huge. That's the end of the `installActions2019-10-06_12-55-49PM.log` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Operating System Checklist for Oracle Database Installation on Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0).  The "Linux x86-64 operating system requirements" for Oracle release 19 are:

> The following Linux x86-64 kernels are supported:
>
> Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4:
>   4.1.12-124.19.2.el7uek.x86_64 or later Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 5: 4.14.35-1818.1.6.el7uek.x86_64 or
>   later Oracle Linux 7.5 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel:
>   3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5: 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
>
> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3: 4.4.162-94.72-default or later
>
> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15: 4.12.14-23-default or later

Maybe a pre-built VM will do the job - see the links [{1}](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html) and [{2}](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html).

Comment: Yeah, mine is `linux 5.0.0-31-generic X86_64`. I'm gonna take a look on the links, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome.  Best of luck!  The VM(s) should make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Same error can occur on supported Linux distros.
In my case Centos 7.8.

The **root cause** was that I unzipped the Oracle 19c installer on my Windows Host, then copied to the Linux client vm.

Unzipping directly in the Linux env resolved the issue for me.
**Credit to:** https://odba.ru/archive/index.php/t-480.html

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the oracle docker image run on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 19c is not supported in Ubuntu.**

To install Oracle 19c in Ubuntu, you have to use Docker.
You can find easy steps here:
https://mkc110891.medium.com/oracle-19c-on-ubuntu-18-04-docker-6898cd2916f9